# MarkLogic matches function with regular expression

Tags: regex, string, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9

I am new to XQuery so could you please help me to understand what is `&#xA7;` and `&#xA7;.*$` in below MarkLogic XQuery:

```
if (matches($cite, '&#xA7;'))
  replace($cite,'&#xA7;.*$','')
```

here `$cite := "HI CONST Preamble"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regex, the `$` in a regex expression [is an anchor point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#anchors) to the end of the input string value.

`&#xA7;` is a [numeric entity reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#:%7E:text=A%20numeric%20character%20reference%20refers,%26%23%20nnnn%20%3B&text=%26%23x%20hhhh%20%3B,code%20point%20in%20hexadecimal%20form.) of the `§` character, and `.` is a [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#character-classes) and the `*` is a [quantifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#quantifiers) meaning zero to many.

The `matches()` expression is testing whether the `$cite` contains the `§` character. If it does, then it attempts to `replace()` the `§` and all of the characters following it until the end of the input with nothing.

For example:

```
let $cite := "HI CONST Preamble"
return
  if (matches($cite, '§')) 
  then replace($cite,'§.*$','') 
  else "no match"
```

returns: "no match" because it doesn't contain the `§` at all.

However, this:

```
let $cite := "HI CONST Preamble §foo bar baz."
return
  if (matches($cite, '§')) 
  then replace($cite,'§.*$','') 
  else "no match"
```

Returns: "HI CONST Preamble" because it does contain `§`, so `§foo bar baz.` is replaced with "".